# How can I pass parameters from the outside to an implementation of an inteface

Tags: java, android, generics, parameters, interface

I created a generic data structure and implemented to it a custom iterator,
that iterator receive an interface that has a function, each object in the data structure is sent to the function from the interface on the object.

Here is how I do that:

The interface:

```
public interface QTreeAction<T> {
    void actToDo(T Param);
}
```

The iterator:

```
public void Iterate(QNode qNode, QTreeAction<T> action)
{
    if (qNode == null)
        return;

    for (int j = 0; j < qNode.objList.size(); j++)
    {
        action.actToDo(qNode.objList.get(j).Object);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        this.Iterate(qNode.Nodes.get(i), action);
    }
}
```

And the call:

```
public void Render(float fDelta, Canvas g) {
    g.drawRGB(255, 255, 10);
    g.setMatrix(this.gameMatrix);

    ohHandler.render(new QTreeAction<Tile>() {
        @Override
        public void actToDo(Tile Param) {
            Param.render(fDelta, g);
        }
    });
    this.pPlayer.render(fDelta, g);
}
```

(ohHandler has the node and calls the iterator)

The render function:

```
public void render(float fDelta, Canvas g) {
    g.drawBitmap(StaticDataHolder.GameTextures.blocks[ttType.getValue()],
            this.vecTilePosition.getX(), this.vecTilePosition.getY(), null);
}
```

As you see Param.render requires 2 parameters that are provided by the function, however at this situation there is an error and it asks me to make the params as final but it throws and error at runtime.

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Do you mean there's an error if you *do* make the parameters `final`? What's the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can only reference final variables inside an anonymous class.

This should do the trick:

```
public void Render(float fDelta, Canvas g) {
    final Cavas gFinal = g;
    final float fDeltaFinal = fDelta;
    ohHandler.render(new QTreeAction<Tile>() {
        @Override
        public void actToDo(Tile Param) {
            Param.render(fDeltaFinal , gFinal);
        }
    });
    this.pPlayer.render(fDelta, g);
}
```

Comment: I edited my code a bit, what if I need to change the canvas inside the function?

Comment: @HuMMeR-SI you will be able to alter the state of `Canvas g` with no problem, but you won't be able to use `g = new Canvas();` (or something similar), that's all.

Comment: You are free to change whatever you want. But the variables you are passing from one method to an anonymous class must be final.